# How to automate email server testing with Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, encryption

I am fiddling with a home-built email encryption device.  I'm sending email with Outlook 2010 from a local email address to my Yahoo webmail to test.  I'm doing this quite a lot as I fool with the encryption hardware.  Instead of composing the test emails (1 unencrypted, 1 encrypted) each time is there a way I can make sending two pre-drafted emails at one or two clicks apart?

Comment: What has this got to do with PGP? We don't know anything about your homebuilt device, how to answer any questions to it?

Comment: I didn't ask about the device.  I asked how to reduce all the typing I do to send the same two emails over and over and over again.

Comment: So your problem hasn't got anything to do with encryption but is "how to automatically send a predrafted mail from within Outlook with one or two clicks"? Be specific on your problem and remove the irrelevant stuff around it. As long as it hasn't got anything to do with specific encryption protocols/implementations, don't use their tags for spamming.

Comment: There was nothing vague whatsoever about this question. I follow the FAQ question writing guidelines to the letter. The FAQ says to "Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you". So I included a concise description of the purpose of my desire to send the same pre-drafted emails over and over again.  The fact that the very first person to attempt an answer provided a complete resolution with one sentence confirms the simplicity of the question.  People come here for help guys, be helpful.

Comment: Your question probably would have received much better feedback if you would have used proper tags (encryption, especially PGP, didn't have *anything* in common with your actual question, this is regarded as spamming), maybe a better headline (eg. "How to automate sending mails in Outlook 2010") and somehow divided up your text in two parts: short motivation, then a clear and defined question in another paragraph. People are here to help, but they're investing valuable time and don't want to do this on bad written, vague questions leading to dozens of follow-up refinements and questions.

Comment: After that explanation I do see your point.  My question was a valid one, but _should_ have been titled better and the body of the question could have been organized differently.  My choice of tags was excessive.  I'll be more targeted in the future.

Comment: Excessive use of tags isn't bad as long as they're the right ones. Using tags actually is very important for the software to link possible answers to questions and it pings people receiving notifications on questions on some tags, but choose wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) (VBA) in Outlook to write macros to draft and send the emails, you can then assign the Macro to a button and/or keyboard shortcut.

More info here: [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: thanks techie007 that is just what I was looking for.  My company forbids the use of VB scripting.  I'm so unaccustomed to its use it didn't even occur to me.